# Py.test и русские символы

Tags: python, unicode, pytest

Пытаюсь использовать такой код:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("array, number_of, expected", TEST_FRAME_CHUNKS, ids=IDS_TEST_FRAME_CHUNKS)
def test_chunks(array, number_of, expected):
    # code ...
```

В `IDS_TEST_FRAME_CHUNKS` названия на русском языке.

Но когда тесты выполняются, вывод в консоли не радует:

```
test_chunks.py::test_chunks[\u0414\u043b\u0438\u043d\u0430 
\u043f\u043e\u0434\u043c\u0430\u0441\u0441\u0438\u0432\u0430 
\u0440\u0430\u0432\u043d\u0430 0]
```

Хотелось бы адекватного вывода русскоязычного текста. Пытался использовать хук:

```
def pytest_make_parametrize_id(val):
    return repr(val)
```

но он не срабатывает.

Как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    'array, number_of, expected',
    [
        pytest.param(*test_args, id=test_id)
        for test_args, test_id in zip(TEST_FRAME_CHUNKS, IDS_TEST_FRAME_CHUNKS)
    ]
)
def test_chunks(array, number_of, expected):
    ...
```

> test_chunks.py::test_chunks[Длина подмассива равна 0]

(Правда, я совсем не уверен, что пихать неанглийский текст в айдишники это хорошая идея)

Comment: Это работает, спасибо! Это нужно для отчетности и интеграцией с jenkins.