# Байт строки pytest

Tags: python, utf-8, pytest

Отображается байт строки вместо русских слов

```
\u0410\u043f\u043f\u0430\u0440\u0430\u0442
```

в `@pytest.mark.parametrize` при считывание из текстового файла. В файле  кодировка utf-8 указана.

Comment: пожалуйста, отформатируйте содержимое вопроса и прикрепите свой код

Comment: Автор, видимо пытается понять, что при `print()` у него выходит кириллица.

Comment: Про parametrize есть вот https://automated-testing.info/t/pytest-krivo-otobrazhaet-kejsy-parametrizaczii-na-russkom/17908

Comment: Посмотрите вот этот вариант: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/768407/1365

Answer (score 0):

Add to pytest.ini

```ini
disable_test_id_escaping_and_forfeit_all_rights_to_community_support = true
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]